# How to repost a form to an external URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building payment gateway integration into my MVC 5 app. Their payment process starts with me presenting a form to collect data, and posting that form to their gateway. I would prefer to post the form to my action method, for some validation and logging, and then post it on to their url. The form data is sent to them using a nromal POST request, i.e. with form data, not URL params. How can I achieve this in an MVC 5 action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just do

```
string theirUrl = "http://example.com?foo=bar";

return this.Redirect(theirUrl);
```

from your action method.